# VBA - Import the first Sheet from a closed workbook to an named sheet in active workbook

Tags: vba, excel, import

I'm new to VBA, and I'm looking for a piece of code that allows me to select an Excel file, and import the first sheet from that file to an named sheet (that already exists) in active workbook (the one that runs the macro).

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/import-sheets.html

Comment: That one serves as a good tutorial, but it opens the excel files from a fixed specified location, then add the sheets in those after the last sheet in active workbook. My real problem is not the location the files are, but how do I copy the first sheet to a named sheet in my active workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim sd As Worksheet, rd As Range
    Set sd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final Destination")
    Set rd = sd.Range("A1")
    filespec = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filespec)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Cells.Copy rd
    wb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Simple as that! That what I needed. Just changed Sheets("Sheet1").Activate to Sheets(1).Activate and it worked the way I wanted. Thanks

Comment: @Gary , I was just about to use this and had a couple of questions.  Why sd for worksheet and rd for range?  I know you need something, just wondering if it was short for something.  Also,  I understand that variables that are not dimensioned are  assigned Variant by default.  In the code above, should wb be `DIM wb as Workbook` and filespec be `DIM filespec as String`?

Comment: I feel like I am missing something.  When I run this code, it opens the selected workbook and then closes it asking if I want to save changes, but nothing appears in the the work book where I am running the code from.  I even tried expanding the range from A1 to A1:H1000.   It took longer to execute but still nothing in the end.

Comment: Dang that took a bit.  in the code above `Sheets("Sheet1").Activate` apparently needed to be `wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate`